# Git wrongly interprets that files names have changed after I pull

Tags: git, bitbucket, filenames, pull, core.autocrlf

I normally work on mac and maintain a bitbucket repository (git). I have no problem pulling my repository on mace.

But when I pull my repository on Windows (Win7), it interprets the filenames wrong and show two files by the same name, one to be deleted and one unkown (basically not added yet). What can I do to fix the problem? This is not line ending issue inside file but it may be line ending issue in file name. Please help.

[image]

As you can see it shows two find.php, one to be deleted and the other to be added. Something to do with how git interprets file names when it stores in repository?

### Update

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    .htaccess
    deleted:    400.shtml
    deleted:    401.shtml
    deleted:    403.shtml
....
Untracked files:
 (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
    .htaccess
    400.shtml
    401.shtml
    403.shtml
```

Comment: It may be a case sensitivity issue. What are the real names of those files?

Comment: I attached the screenshot. I think it is text encoding issue between utf8 and windows7

Comment: What git client are you using? Can you post the output of the plain `git status` command?

Comment: @Leon I am using SourceTree. I have added git status in the question. Thx

Comment: What's in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Doesn't `git reset` help?

Comment: @Leon .gitignore is empty. I have not tried `git reset` coz it could be dangerous. I have already made a lot of changes, I dont want to loose that too. I can stash changes but then I have huge number of files.

Comment: `git reset` (without `--hard`) is not dangerous. It will simply clear your index. All changes in the working tree will be preserved.

Comment: Ok did `git reset` still the same result, the order now different. First shows all untracked files, then comes all files to be deleted (both are same file names). I think it is encoding issue of file names but don't know how to fix it

Comment: @Leon ok it is resolved now. The issue was in checkout. `git checkout -f HEAD` resolved it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually not with file name encoding as I had suspected but with git checkout. The issue arised because the code was pulled but it was **not checked out**

### More Detail

I pulled the same repository again on another Windows machine and ran into same issue but this time I saw the actual error,

> Cloning into...
>   warning: templates not found C:\Program Files\Git\share\git-core\templates
>   Checking out files: 100% (917/917), done.
>   fatal: unable to checkout working tree
>   warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
>   You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
>   and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'

By running the above command,`git checkout -f HEAD` it immediate resolved the two file issues.

But on my mac the issue was still not resolved. I received the following error when I used `git checkout -f HEAD`

> $ git checkout -f HEAD error: unable to create file
>   text\description.txt (No such file or directory) Your branch is
>   up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

I used a trick to create a dummy description.txt file inside text folder which got rid of the error. The command now ran successfully but I would still see the two files (delet, untracked).

Then inside SourceTree I tried switching repositories and also issues pull request. After some time the issue got resolve automatically. I think it was the `git checkout -f HEAD` command that resolved the issue.

So it turned out to be more tricky than I had expected.